# JWT is not stored... How to view it?

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt, koa, koa2

Can't understand the nodejs Authentication (KoaJS2).

I have this piece of code  :

```
router.post("/login", koaBody, (ctx, next) => {
  const data = ctx.request.body;
  db
    .any("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC")
    .then(function(data) {

      token = jwt.sign(data, token_secret, {
        expiresIn: "24h" // expires in 24 hours
      });

      console.log(ctx.request.header);
      // ctx.set("token", `test`);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // error;
    });
```

Where is the token stored after I sign it?

There is no "Authentication" header...

Comment: The two techniques for storing the JWT are localstorage and cookies (that I'm aware of)

Comment: Are cookies stored only from client side Javascript? 
I can't figure it out doing it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

On the **server side** you neary to the right thing. What you need to do: return back the token to the client:

```
router.post("/login", koaBody, (ctx, next) => {
  const data = ctx.request.body;

  // ...
  // extract username and password from body
  // ...

  db
    .any("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id ASC") // here using and checking credentials is also missing ;-)
    .then(function(data) {

      // create the token
      token = jwt.sign(data, token_secret, {
        expiresIn: "24h" // expires in 24 hours
      });

      // now you have to pass it back to the client
      // the token is NOT stored on the server side!
      ctx.body = { 'token': token }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // error;
    });
```

On the **client side** - if you get back a token in the body - you store it e.g. in the local storage

I am using angular 2 on the client side, here the code (client side login service) could look like this:

```
login(credentials) {

    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    const reqopt: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
      headers: headers
    });

    // credentials: username, password -- 
    return this.http.post(...your_api_endpoint_ + '/login', credentials, reqopt)
      .map(res => {
        const data = res.json();
        if (data && data.token) {
          localStorage.setItem('token', data.token); // <--- here you store your token
        }
      });
}
```

Each time you now hit your API again, do not forget to provide you token in the header and check it on the server side (`JWT.verify()`).

Here you can find a more general introduction to JWT:
https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec

Hope that helps.